# Categorical model of binding / first class modules

Tags: pl.programming-languages, ct.category-theory

Binders are explained using presheaves ([Pitts/Gabbay A new approach to Abstract Syntax with variable binding](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?client=safari&rls=en&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&cites=2646104348392885758))

What is the equivalent (categorical) theory to explain first class modules as in [1ML](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/1ml/) ?

Comment: One can understand modules (including first class modules) in a language with singleton kinds so any categorical model of singleton kinds will suffice.

Comment: And what would be a categorical model of singleton kinds ?